# WebGLRenderer serrated image

Tags: three.js, webgl

When I move the camera with this example http://www.luizgadao.com.br/site/ all images are serrated. If o renderer is "CanvasRenderer" it is not work.
Anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

That's a limitation of `CanvasRenderer`. There is no solution.

However, for a site like this maybe you could use `CSS3DRenderer`:
http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/css3d_youtube.html

Comment: No, with "CanvasRenderer" it is work perfect!
Look [link]http://luizgadao.com.br/site/render_canvas.html[/link] only "WebGLRenderer" all images are serated.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I misunderstood what you meant with "serrated". What do you mean with "serrated"?

Comment: "Serrated" that the images is distorted when render with "WebGLRenderer"!
Look the image [example](http://luizgadao.com.br/site/webgl_vs_canvas.jpg). <br/>
Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: `new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } )`. However, it's currently disabled on Chrome/OSX.

Comment: It is true, however any mode to enable "antialias" in Chrome/OSX?

Comment: You'll have to wait. Just one month, hopefully.